# Value Unpack Error in python (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

the following code is working properly on ubuntu distro but the code generates a error in windows

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

import sys
strcmd = "curve -d 3"
f = open("cam_data.dex","r")
for line in f:
 (x,y,z)=line.split(",")
 strcmd = strcmd+" -p"+" "+x+" "+y+" "+z.rstrip()

print(strcmd)
print("\nDONE\n")
```

Im not able to find what the error is any help regarding this will be highly helpfull

Comment: what is the content of your .dex file ? share a sample data with us. 
problem in this line , (x,y,z)=line.split(",") .split() -> list of strings ,Return a list of the words in String delimiter string.

Comment: 1,2,3
3,2,1
4,5,6
6,5,4
7,8,9
9,8,7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue :**

`(x,y,z)=line.split(",")` this will return a list which cannot be mapped to three variables

**Fixed Code**

Here is what you can do:

```
import sys
strcmd = "curve -d 3"
f = open("cam_data.dex","r")
for line in f:
    x=" ".join(line.split(","))
    strcmd = strcmd+" -p"+" "+x

print(strcmd)
print("\nDONE\n")
```

**Output :**

```
curve -d 3 -p 1 2 3 3 2 1 4 5 6 6 5 4 7 8 9 9 8 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform `split` on `f` depending on the delimiter and iterate over it.

```
import sys
strcmd = "curve -d 3"
f = open("cam_data.dex","r")
for line in f.split():
    (x,y,z)=line.split(",")
    strcmd = strcmd+" -p"+" "+x+" "+y+" "+z.rstrip()

print(strcmd)
print("\nDONE\n")
# curve -d 3 -p 1 2 3 -p 3 2 1 -p 4 5 6 -p 6 5 4 -p 7 8 9 -p 9 8 7                                                    
# DONE
```